# How to write a function like which.min but for bottom 3 values?

Tags: r

I want to write a function that gives the 3 indices of the bottom 3 values of a vector -- just like which.min, but the bottom 3 indices instead of the bottom index.

I wrote a function (minfunc, below) that can be called by apply() to find the bottom 3 values of a vector. But right now I have no function to find the *indices* of those 3 minimum values.

```
minfunc <- function(x) {
  min1 <- min(x)
  min2 <- min(x[x != min(x)])
  min3 <- -sort(-x, TRUE)[3]
  cmin <- c(min1, min2, min3)
  return(cmin)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way. First provide reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
X <- sample.int(20, 20)
X
# [1] 17  5  1 10  4  2 20 18  8  7 16  9 19  6 14 15 12  3 13 11
```

Now the indices of the bottom 3:

```
head(order(X), 3)
# [1]  3  6 18
X[head(order(X), 3)]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

To create a function:

```
which.mins <- function(x, mins=3) {
    head(order(x), mins)
}
which.mins(X, 3)
# [1]  3  6 18
which.mins(X, 5)
# [1]  3  6 18  5  2
```

Comment: I'd use `order(x)[1:mins]` since it's slightly faster. Regardless +1

Comment: NIce adjustment.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect! Just to be clear, when I define the function I see I can write function(x, mins) rather than function(x, mins=3). Putting in =3 doesn't change anything either way. Is this a typo, or is there some reason for that =3 bit? It seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: That provides a default value for the `mins=` argument. If you want 3, you can just call the function with `which.min(X)`, but if you want more or fewer, you specify a value for `mins=`.